# How to save the conversational data (chatbot history) using bot framework composer?

Tags: save, bot-framework-composer

The echo bot template of bot framework SDK （https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp） is difficult to duplicate in the bot made by bot framework composer. Is there any way to save the chat history with bot framework composer?